# Is there a German publication that would be a resource for reading that is more informal, conversational?

Tags: vocabulary, colloquial, resource, online-resource

In short, I'm looking for german reading material that is more diverse than the newspapers I currently read.

I do quite a bit of reading online and listening in German, but most of the resources I use are news based. As I've tried to improve my listening comprehension through watching youtube videos or shows through Netflix, I have found that the biggest issue I have is that there are still many vocabulary words or expressions that are used informally or in conversation that I have had no previous exposure. If there aren't captions it's often difficult to go back and parse what was said to search in a dictionary.

I am wondering if someone has reading suggestions for German resources or publications written in a conversational or informal style that would expose me to such vocabulary and phrases? Is there something analogous to [the Onion](https://www.theonion.com/) in german? Alternatively, could you suggest several non-news focused publications or sites directed toward a younger, urban audience?

Comment: How is *The Onion* informal? Quoting from the first article I saw: *A deep appreciation dawning upon him as he came to understand the sheer wonder radiated by such a rare occurrence, conversation-starved man Ryan Kennedy reportedly finally treated bumping into his coworker as the exquisite treasure it is, sources confirmed Wednesday.*

Comment: Thomas, check out the magazine "Deutsch Perfekt" (there are articles according to a certain level of knowledge ("leicht - mittel - schwer")

Answer (score 3):

[Der Postillon](https://www.der-postillon.com/) is a satirical news site, if youre looking for something like a German version of the Onion. But the Onion isn't exactly informal or conversational; it mimics a news style.

Comment: The Postillon mimics a news style as well :-)). Upvote for the recommendation, it's worth checking every day. The [Hydroxochloroquine side effects](https://www.der-postillon.com/2020/06/trump-hydroxychloroquin.html) were illuminating. Or the idea that the number and equipment of the soldiers suddenly sent to the Lincoln Memorial indicates the [discovery of a 400 million barrel oil field](https://www.der-postillon.com/2020/06/erdoel-in-washington.html) ...

Answer (score 2):

Go to the tabloids' web pages and read the user comments to the news instead of the news themselves ;-) But be aware that the language there will not only be informal but often also local (colloquial speech is often close to dialects) and quite frequently also offending.

Answer (score 1):

When focusing on "vocabulary words or expressions that are used informally or in conversation", I would recommend German comics. An obvious example would be *Lustiges Taschenbuch*.

https://www.lustiges-taschenbuch.de/ausgaben/alle-ausgaben/ltb-564#preview

I found that the expressions range from simple every-day phrases to quite complicated ones, which do not appear directly in a grammar or text book.